# Highcharts Grid Line Width (or Color) - Single Line

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, scatter-plot

I have the following `Highcharts` (http://www.highcharts.com) scatter chart.  Note that the axes start at -10 and stop at 10, with 0 in the middle.  I want each 0 line to be a different width or color from all the others.  Should be easy but I can't find in the API documentation how to do.  All I can find is how to change properties for all lines.  Has anyone done this or have suggestions?

Outside of the API I looked into using Javascript (specifically jQuery) to update the element's style but the only specific part (`d`) I could easily use to find which line to update isn't always the same.  The element looks like.....

```
<path stroke-width="10" opacity="1" stroke="#D8D8D8" d="M 293.5 72 L 293.5 502" fill="none"></path>
```

Thanks.

[image: Scatter Chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement [plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines). Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/8eLced2u/) out.

In `yAxis`, I have set a green line at value of 70.

In `xAxis`, I have set a blue line at value of 170.

You may play around with the `color` and `width` as well.

Comment: Works fantastic and easy.  Perfect, thank you very much.  Speedy too.